# Roots of an equation in integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We will be working with positive integers. I have this equation:
$$qn-qx-n+1=0$$

and I must prove that in order for it to have a solution in $\{1,2,...n\}$, $n$ must be of the form $n=aq+1$ for some $a$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its not an equation.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the distributive property to rewrite the equation as $q(n - x) - n + 1 = 0$, and so $n = q(n - x)  + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$qx = n(q-1) + 1 \Rightarrow x = \dfrac{n(q-1)+1}{q} = n + \dfrac{1-n}{q} \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow 1-n = aq, a \in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow n = -aq + 1$.